# Cloudwatch VPC interface endpoint times out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-vpc

I am trying to connect my EC2 host setup inside a private subnet to publish logs to cloud watch. I have setup a VPC interface endpoint for com.amazonaws.us-east-1.logs.
Both the interface endpoint and EC2 are in private subnet.

My Security groups

1. Security Group rules for Interface endpoint

   > Inbound rule
   >
   > Type      Protocol   Port Range   Destination
   >
   > All TCP   TCP        0 - 65535    sg-OfEC2Server
   >
   > Outbound rules - None
2. Security Group rules for EC2

   > Inbound rules - None
   >
   > Outbound rule
   >
   > Type      Protocol   Port Range   Destination
   >
   > All TCP TCP        0 - 65535    sg-OfInterfaceEndpoint

The cloudwatch agent keeps timing out, so i sense that there is an issue with my security group rules but none of the trouble shoot steps helped.

Comment: Shouldn't the outbound rule be for ` sg-ForEC2Server`?

Comment: updated the question.

Comment: The DNS settings for VPC are enabled?

Comment: DNS resolution and DNS hostnames are enabled

Comment: I assume the instance has role with permissions to call CW, interfaces policies are also permisive?

Comment: Yep Interface policy is allow everything and I have a role attached to EC2 instance profile  that allows the following:
               "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"

Comment: Have you tested manual connection to CW logs, using `aws logs` cli, just to know that this is not CW agent specific issue?

Comment: Yep this command also times out:
aws logs put-log-events --log-group-name vpctest --log-stream-name vpctest --log-events file://data.json --region us-east-1

Comment: When you created the endpoint, `Enable DNS name` was also enabled?

Comment: I think so, I will create a new endpoint to double-check. Also, do I need to make any changes to the routing table? As per the docs I don't think so

Comment: No. Route tables are for Gateway (s3 and ddb) endpoints.

Comment: BTW. How do you connect the the instance? It has no `inbout` rules? You can't ssh to it. So how did you verify that `aws cli` doesn't work?

Comment: The new endpoint doesn't work either. I added an inbound rule now I am using a bastion host to ssh into the instance.

Comment: I think I know what's happening. I recreated your setup, and got same issue.

Comment: Your outboud rule in EC2 will not allow to contact to DNS server for resolution of dns of the endpoint. Changing output rule to 0.0.0.0/0 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I **recreated** your setup and encountered the **same problem** when using same security groups as yours.

What I found is that the issue is caused by the following outbound rule:

> All TCP TCP 0 - 65535 sg-OfInterfaceEndpoint

This allows EC2 to connect only to the interface endpoint, and nowhere else. Changing it to the CIDR of my VPC (10.1.0.0/16) **fixed the problem** and I could use the interface endpoint.

I think that the root cause of the timeout was that with the original outbound rule, your (and mine) private instance could not connect to DHCP or DNS servers for the VPC. Subsequently, resolution of DNS name of the `logs` endpoint was not possible.